# text section exceeds available space in board for esp32 + bluetooth + wifi + httpclient

Tags: esp32

I trying to learn how to write arduino code for an ESP32 WROOM 32.  I want my esp32 to make an http request to a RESTFUL API i've set up. Thus, my esp32 will need wifi access. I was planning to use Bluetooth to tell my esp32 what wifi connection details to use and the specific address of the RESTFUL API end point.  I read some documenation online and people suggested that I would need `BluetoothSerial.h` for bluetooth connection, `<WiFi.h>` for wifi connection and `<HTTPClient.h>` for make HTTP requests.

But the moment I include all 3 packages and initialize a few variables and try to compile, my Arduino IDE gives me the following error:

```
text section exceeds available space in boardSketch uses 1428393 bytes (108%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.

Global variables use 55740 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory, leaving 271940 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
Sketch too big; see https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360013825179 for tips on reducing it.
Error compiling for board ESP32-WROOM-DA Module.
```

This is the code that caused the error:

```cpp
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
const char* ssid = "";
const char* pass = "";
String apiUrl = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //Optional
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      delay(100);
  }
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
}

void loop() {
  delay(20);
}
```

As you can see, I haven't even begun any real coding and I already get an error that suggest my ESP32 doesn't have necessary resources.

Did I do something wrong?  What else should I consider?

---

UPDATES

@jsotola

When I comment out the lines `BluetoothSerial SerialBT;` and `SerialBT.begin("ESP32test");`, then the program compiles and I see this message:

```
Wrote 726112 bytes (464336 compressed) at 0x00010000 in 7.0 seconds (effective 828.6 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
```

So does that mean just those two lines of bluetooth related code takes up about 700kb?

@hcheung - If I change the `Tools > Partition Scheme` from `Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)` to `8MB with spiffs (3MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)`, then Arduino IDE compiles and writes the code to my ESP32.  However, when I try to use my Android phones Serial Bluetooth app to try to connect to the ESP32, I get the error `Connection failed: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret:-1`.  So it seems the partition scheme affects bluetooth functionality.

I also tried changing the `Tools > Flash Size` from 4MB to 8MB.  And I get the same behaviour - 4MB doesn't compile.  But 8MB does compile.  But after it compiles my phone can't connect via bluetooth.

And just to be sure, the following code below from `File > Examples > BluetoothSerial > SerialtoSerialBT` only works with Flash Size 4MB and Default Partition Scheme of `Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)`

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: what is the program size if you remove all of the bluetooth program lines?

Comment: From Arduino IDE, click on menu "Tools -> Partition Scheme" to configure your board with larger flash memory size.

Comment: thanks @jsotola i updated my question with details to your question.  Seems like bluetooth lines use up half the memory/flash size?

Comment: thanks @hcheung, i updated my question with details to your suggestion. Seems like changing partition scheme or the flash size lets the program compile, but it disrupts the bluetooth connection

Comment: choose other options than 8MB unless you know for sure that your ESP32 came with 8MB flash memory. Changing the partition scheme has nothing to do with Bluetooth functionality.